# Pass Data,Share global variable,Singleton?

Tags: ios

I have a UITabbarController with three UINavigationControllers.And each navigation controllers has a UITableViewController as rootViewController. It's a typical design in many apps.Now I want to share a object between these three UITableViewController in their UINavigationControllers.I have the following ideas:

1. In UITabbarViewController, I can declare a property,maybe 'strong'.Each UITableViewController can access to the object use`self.tabbarcontroller.object`
2. Create a singleton that keeps this object. But it may cause singleton abuse.Some topic advise use dependency injection to avoid the abuse.But it seems it could not satisfy my requirement.
3. Make the object a global variable.I really do not want to take this method.

I prefer to use method 1. Any ideas about the data passing?

Comment: First method is preferable. Also you can use NSUserDefult if you having less data to pass to next VC.

Comment: I would declare the object as a property in the tabbarController and each tableViewController and give a reference from the tabbarController to each tableViewController on creation.

Comment: @ChandraVaghasiya thank you.. And NSUserDefault is a system singleton, use it to keep my object is exactly the method2 :-)

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff any reason? If I have to access the object or set the object many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to pass it to the ViewController just like an Android intent extra then i would go for method 1.

If you need to store it and access it multiple times from various classes then i would go for method 2 or 3, maybe 2 is more clear.

Hope this helps.